# Why Long.valueOf(stateMap.get("time")) when using Base64 encrytion giving java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hashmap, base64, classcastexception

For understanding purpose I am combining three different java file code in on Test.java file below. Line `long tokenTime = Long.valueOf(decodedMap.get("time"));`  giving exception.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Long> stateMap = new HashMap<>();
    stateMap.put("userId",123L);
    stateMap.put("resId", 456L);
    stateMap.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());

    String encodedString = jsonBase64Encode(stateMap);

    Map<String, Long> decodedMap = jsonBase64Decode(encodedString);
    long tokenTime = Long.valueOf(decodedMap.get("time"));
    System.out.println(tokenTime);

}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static String jsonBase64Encode(Map<String, Long> stateMap){

    if(stateMap == null)
        return "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    for( String key : stateMap.keySet() ){
        jsonObject.put(key, stateMap.get(key).toString());
    }
    byte[] jsonBytes = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
    try {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jsonBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}


public static Map<String, Long> jsonBase64Decode(String state)
{
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(state))
        return null;
    String decodedStr = null;
    try {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(state);
        decodedStr = new String(decodedBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(decodedStr))
        return null;
    Map<String, Long> stateMap = new Gson().fromJson(decodedStr, 
            new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
    return stateMap;
}
```

}

I am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at com.test.document.utils.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

Comment: Base64 is not encryption to begin with, anyone can decode that message

Comment: Is that causing exception?

Comment: The test example is not complete.  Please provide the imports so that I can tell what libs to import.  My unverified hypothesis is that the decode json code is returning a map that has String values instead of Long values;  thus causing the exception at the reported line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`Map<String, Long> stateMap = new Gson().fromJson(decodedStr, 
            new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());`

to

`Map<String, Long> stateMap = new Gson().fromJson(decodedStr, 
            new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Long>>() {}.getType());`

Answer (score 3):

That means your runtime map is returning a string when your code was compiled with it expecting a Long:

```
decodedMap.get("time") //At compile time, this is a Long
```

But when the code runs at runtime, the actual value is a String.

You can replicate it easily by pushing a string into the map:

```
stateMap.put("resId", 456L);
((Map) stateMap).put("time", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

long tokenTime = Long.valueOf(stateMap.get("time"));
```

The last line above raises:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Your JSON needs to be fixed, or you need to change your code to compile against `Long.valueOf(String)`